# Поиск OEP, установка bp на esp-4

Tags: ассемблер, reverse-engineering

Читаю Криса Касперски "Исскуство дизасемблирования". В 38 главе прочитал, что один из способов поиска OEP в запакованном приложении являеться установка точки останова на esp-4... Немогу понять почему esp-4 ?

Comment: Вероятно потому, что код распаковки в самом конце обращается к `[esp-4]`. Можно для проверки упаковать экзешник каким-нибудь upx, и попробовать найти его OEP.